# How to sort results from nearest to farthest with $geoWithin conditional?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, geo

I have the following query to find all documents within particular bounds:

```
db.collection.find({
    "location": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "$box": [
                [165.8694369, -52.61941849999999],
                [-175.831536, -29.2313419]
            ]
        }
    }
});
```

Also I have the coordinates of center of this bounds: `center_lat: -40.900557`, `center_lng: 174.885971`.

Is it possible to sort result documents by nearest to farthest from the center point?

Comment: I'm sure you can use the aggregation framework with a two stage pipeline: a `$match` stage which you can use the `$geoWithin` query and the last `$sort` stage that sorts by `center_lat` and `center_lng`

Comment: @chridam how could I sort from nearest to farthest distance in aggregation framework?

Comment: No too sure, can you try `{ $sort : { center_lat: -1, center_lng: -1 } }`?

Comment: @chridam `center_lat` and `center_lng` are not stored in document but serves as conditional for query.

Comment: Right, my apologies I misread the question, I thought those were fields in the document. However, instead of the `$sort` pipeline stage, you could try the [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) pipeline stage. If that doesn't meet your needs you could also look at the [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/#query-on-geojson-data) query operator.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what abount performance? I'm using shared collections

Comment: The **`$geoNear`** query operator works in sharded collections but performance could be better - there is currently a [JIRA for this](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1982). This post may be useful too [**Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/)

Comment: do you mean `could not be better`?

Comment: It means performance is okay but could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

The $geoWithin operator does not return sorted results. As such, MongoDB can return $geoWithin queries more quickly than geospatial $near or $nearSphere queries, which sort results.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/